Is there a way to use/a workaround for http requests in a localscript in Roblox?
I'm making a roblox game, and am using a localscript to handle some of the ui stuff. I need to use an http request to grab the contents of the local players' inventory (not in-game inventory, but the one with the stuff they can buy from the catalog/marketplace) but you can't use http requests in localscripts, so I'm looking for a workaround. I've also tried putting the code that handles getting the inventory into a separate modulescript. That didn't work, as roblox holds any modulescripts to the restrictions of whatever script they're being run in (at least to my knowledge).
here's some code to illustrate where I am atm:
(here's the modulescript contents:
local gearManagement = {}

function gearManagement.GetGears(player)
    local HttpService = game:GetService("HttpService")
    local Table = "https://inventory.roproxy.com/v2/users/"..player.UserId.."/inventory?assetTypes=Gear&limit=100&sortOrder=Asc"
    local GearResponse = HttpService:RequestAsync({
        Url = Table,
        Method = "GET"
    });
    if GearResponse.Success then
        local TableBody = HttpService:JSONDecode(GearResponse.Body)
        for i, v in pairs(TableBody) do
            return v
        end
    end 
end

function gearManagement.CheckForViewableInventory(player)
    local HttpService = game:GetService("HttpService")
    local CanSeeInventory = "https://inventory.roproxy.com/v1/users/"..player.UserId.."/can-view-inventory"
    local Response = HttpService:RequestAsync({
        Url = CanSeeInventory,
        Method = "GET"
    });
end

return gearManagement

(and here's the localscript)
local HttpService = game:GetService("HttpService")
local players = game:GetService("Players")
local player = players.LocalPlayer
local serverStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")
-- WHY THE HELL DOES THIS NOT WORK???????????? ITS RIGHT THERE GAME, THE UI FOLDER IS RIGHT THERE, WHY ARENT YOU SEEING IT
-- ^i have found out how, local scripts can't interact w/ server stuff
local gearCardBase = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.gearCard
local gearManagement = require(script.Parent.gearManagement)

local Response = gearManagement.CheckForViewableInventory(player)

if Response.Success then -- If it doesnst work, then idk    
    local Body = HttpService:JSONDecode(Response.Body) -- Decoding the table
    if Body.canView == true then
        -- Continue Code
        local Gears = gearManagement.GetGears(player)
        local gearRowNum = 0
        if Gears ~= nil then -- Avoid errors
            for i, v in pairs(Gears) do
                -- print(v.name, v.assetId)
                local newGearCard = gearCardBase:Clone()
                newGearCard.Parent = script.Parent
                newGearCard.Visible = true
                newGearCard.Interactable = true
                
                local gearRowOffset =  gearRowNum * 4 + 1
                local trueI = i-gearRowOffset
                
                local xPositioningNum = 121 + 21 -- 2nd num is the space between the two cards
                local finalXPositioningNum = xPositioningNum * trueI
                newGearCard.Position.X = newGearCard.Position.X + finalXPositioningNum
                
                local yPositioningNum = 166 + 21 -- 2nd num is the space between the two cards
                local finalYPositioningNum = yPositioningNum * gearRowNum
                newGearCard.Position.Y = newGearCard.Position.Y + finalYPositioningNum
                
                newGearCard.gearImage.Image = "rbxthumb://type=Asset&w=150&h=150&id="..v.assetId
            end
        end
    else
        -- might put a warning here
    end
end

(sorry for my flowery language in the code comments, i was a bit frustrated lol)

The best way of achieving this is probably using AvatarEditorService

To get the exact functionality you want, you could use RemoteEvents and RemoteFunctions to send and reiceve data from the server. Try something like this.

Create a RemoteFunction in ReplicatedStorage called "Action"
In a script, use local Response = game.ReplicatedStorage.Action:InvokeServer() to ask the server to send you information
On the server, use the lines

game.ReplicatedStorage.Action.OnServerInvoke = function()
   return gearManagement.CheckForViewableInventory(player)
end

This will get the information on the server and send it to the client.

Roblox does not recommend using their web api inside your game. a great (client sided) solution for this would be using AvatarEditorService
here you can do the following:
local AvatarEditor = game:GetService("AvatarEditorService");

AvatarEditor.PromptAllowInventoryReadAccessCompleted:Connect(function(Result)
   if (Result == Enum.AvatarPromptResult.Success) then
      local Page = AvatarEditor:GetInventory({Enum.AvatarAssetType.Gear});

      Items = {};
      while (not Page.IsFinished) do
         local pageItems = Page:GetCurrentPage();
         for _, v in pairs(pageItems) do
            table.insert(Items, v);
         end
      end

      -- all gears inside "Items" variable
   else
      -- player denied permission
   end
end)

AvatarEditor:PromptAllowInventoryReadAccess();



I tried to use this code, but it gave me the error "Unable to cast to array" at the part that says local Page = AvatarEditor:GetInventory(Enum.AvatarAssetType.Gear);

@TheLemon27 i edited my answer, it should be correct now.

Another error: "IsFinished is not a valid member of InventoryPages "Instance" " at while (not Page:IsFinished()) do

@TheLemon27 yes mb i made it out of my head so it had some errors, i fixed that now!
